# How to Send an AWS Raw Email with pdf file attached to it in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, email-attachments, amazon-ses

Here's what I've done so far

```
public static async Task<bool> SendEmailWithAttachmentAsync(EmailObj emlData)
    {
        var replyToAddresses = new List<string>();
        replyToAddresses.Add("Email");

        try
        {
            var options = new CredentialProfileOptions
            {
                AccessKey = "1234",
                SecretKey = "5678"
            };

            var profile = new CredentialProfile("default", options);
            var sharedFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();
            sharedFile.RegisterProfile(profile);

            using (var client = new 
            AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2))
            {
                var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();

                bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "Hello World. Please view the attachment.";
                bodyBuilder.TextBody = "Hello World. Please view the attachment.";

                var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", "Email"));
                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "Email"));

                mimeMessage.Subject = "Hello World";
                
                //using (var messageStream = new MemoryStream())
                //{
                    MemoryStream messageStream = new MemoryStream();
                    
                    emlData.Report.ExportToPdf(messageStream);
                    messageStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add("File.pdf", messageStream, new 
                ContentType("application", "pdf"));
                mimeMessage.WriteTo(messageStream);
                
                var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest {
                        Source = senderAddress,
                        Destinations = new List<string> { "Email" },
                        RawMessage = new RawMessage(messageStream)
                    };

                var response = await client.SendRawEmailAsync(sendRequest);

                if (response.MessageId != null)
                {
                    messageStream.Close();
                    messageStream.Flush();
                }

                    
                //}
                

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

*I've tried putting code into using(memoryStream){} but doesn't seem to be working.*
**emlData.Report.ExportToPdf(messageStream); In here Report is XtraReport from DevExpress report, the code works as I've done the download part successfully but somehow sending an email doesn't work.**

> Any help would be appreciated, thank you. I've attached an image of what I got in my email.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed the example in [here](https://www.minatcoding.com/blog/tech-tips/tech-tip-send-emails-with-file-attachments-from-a-net-core-app-using-aws-ses) and I was able to send an email with a PDF attachment with MimeKit using this code:

```
public static void ReadPdfIntoMemoryStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    memoryStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
}

public static async Task<bool> SendEmailWithAttachmentAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();

            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "Hello World. Please view the attachment.";
            bodyBuilder.TextBody = "Hello World. Please view the attachment.";

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ReadPdfIntoMemoryStream(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add("Test.pdf", ms, new ContentType("application", "pdf"));
            }

            var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", senderAddress));
            mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", destinationAddress));
            mimeMessage.Subject = "Hello World";

            mimeMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
            using (var messageStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await mimeMessage.WriteToAsync(messageStream);
                var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest { RawMessage = new RawMessage(messageStream) };
                var response = await client.SendRawEmailAsync(sendRequest);
                Console.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `ReadPdfIntoMemoryStream` method emulates yours `emlData.Report.ExportToPdf` and loads a PDF into a memory stream. You can pass this memory stream directly to bodyBuilder attachments. Don't reuse this memory stream to send the raw message. Create a new one.

Comment: I send the memory stream like this
 byte[] pdf = pdfDocument.Save();
  //convert to memory stream
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
    var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest
        {Destinations = new List<string> { "abc@mail.com" }, RawMessage = new 
        RawMessage(stream),
        Source = senderAddress
            };

Comment: I am unable to receive the email with an attachment. anything I am missing

Comment: byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); In this line filename is a static value or anything